# Изменяется ли пунктуация и орфография в издаваемых письмах?

Tags: орфография, авторская-пунктуация

При издании писем насколько можно вмешиваться в авторский текст?

- Если пунктуация и орфография авторская сохраняется, то и в таком, например, случае: *подарили томик Достоевского, Карамазовы* – не исправляем на *подарили томик Достоевского, "Карамазовы"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При издании писем обычно сохраняется авторская орфография и пунктуация, но обязательно перед ними пишется:
"Издается в авторской орфографии и пунктуации".

Известных авторов вообще нежелательно править, корректировать, кто-то принимал правки и при жизни нормально, а кто-то протестовал, например, Достоевский не переносил правок и говорил,что ставит знаки препинания так, как чувствует, а корректоры только портят текст.

Так что лучше написать, что пунктуация и орфография авторская, и ничего не править. Тем более, что правка будет неверна, ведь роман называется "Братья Карамазовы", а Карамазовы - усечённое название, как бы бытовое, для своих, такого названия нет.